# swiper loop bug first item

Tags: angular, loops, swiper.js

at the beginning the swipper works fine, but when in the loop it re-enters the first element the button does not take the function (click). In this function open a modal

it has to be related to the swipper loop

```
 <swiper #swiper [config]="configSlide ">
        <div *ngFor="let i of proyects.proyectsItems; let index = index" class="swiper-slide ">
            <div class="borderImage ">
                <div class="shapeHexaImage ">
                    <div class="shapeHexaImage-2 ">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img class="project-img " [src]="i.imagesProyects[0]">
            <button (click)="openModalProyect( $event, i )" class="button-show-more"> Ver mas </button>
            <p class="textImageProject ">
                {{i.typeProyect}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </swiper>

configSlide: SwiperOptions = {

navigation: {
  nextEl: '.rightPosition',
  prevEl: '.leftPosition'
},
autoplay: {
  delay: 6000,
  disableOnInteraction: false
},
// slideToClickedSlide: true, -- Dejar comentada. Esta propiedad tiene un bug  cuando cambia el slide -- // 
breakpoints: {
  320: {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 20
  },
  576: {
    slidesPerView: 1.7,
    spaceBetween: -60
  },
  770: {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: -50
  },
},
centeredSlides: true,
// initialSlide: 2,  //
loop: true,
slideNextClass: 'swiper-slide-next',
slidePrevClass: 'swiper-slide-prev',
```

}